# MySQL selecting date range but also between

Tags: mysql, dateadd

My db is made of groups of entries (by user) with a row for each day of the week and also groups where there is only 1 row per week of the year.  This week may start Sat, Sun or Mon.
The sql groups all these rows by user id and works fine for the entries where the user has a row for every day
The problem I have is selecting the users rows where there is only one entry per week
Basically if the rows date is 11th Feb 2012 then I need to be able to select that row if the start date criteria falls on that date or within that following week and all rows upto but not including the row where the date column is *after* the end date
I'm trying everything like dateadd in the sql but I just cannot get it to add these rows in.
Hope I've made myself clear.

Say I have two entries in the db
2013-02-02
2013-02-09

I have a start date of 2013-02-05 and an end date of 2012-02-13
I need to get those two row as:
the start date falls on or within the week of 2013-02-02
and I also need 2013-02-09 as the end date falls on or within the week of that date.
Hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what your question is asking.

If your field is of mysql date or datetime type, and you wanted to find if there was an entry for a given week could you not use [MySQL WEEK Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) to find all entries for the given week, you may also need to include a restriction on YEAR too.

You could also include the following week, but you may encounter problems. The main problem being week 52+1 of 2012 wont give week 1 of 2013, but week 1 of 2012.

Comment: Got it eventually  DATE_SUB(coursedate, INTERVAL -6 DAY)>= "'.$startdate.'" AND coursedate<  "'.$enddate.'"

Comment: That should be - DATE_ADD(coursedate, INTERVAL +6 DAY)>= "'.$startdate.'" AND coursedate< "'.$enddate.'"